# DROP DATABASE fails

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 database (let's call it `mydb`) that I would like to delete. However, when I do `db2 drop db mydb` I get back

> SQL1035N  The operation failed because the specified database cannot
>   be  connected to in the mode requested.  SQLSTATE=57019

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.8.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01035n.html here some steps for troubleshooting

Comment: It's probably in use by some applications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
db2 quiesce db immediate
db2 force application all
db2 drop database mydb
```

'Quiesce' forces all users off the specified instance and database and puts it into a quiesced mode. (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008635.html)

'Force application' forces local or remote users or applications off the system to allow for maintenance on a server. (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001951.html)

If that doesn't do the trick, do 'db2stop' and 'db2start' after the 'force application' and then drop the database

Comment: After all that. When I tried to create the sample database using db2sampl command, it gave me the following error:  
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
db2 terminate
```

then run the command:

```
db2sampl
```